# Surveyor gem show results after user submits the survey

Tags: surveyor-gem

Is there any option to show the results of the survey after user submits it to database?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the survey results through the same URL i.e. '/surveys/survey_name/access_code' (no '/take' at the end).

If you are looking to get the data through the console / build an API to get the results try user.response_sets[response_index].responses